# Understanding Keras Callback Output

Tags: pandas, keras

My Keras model below with callback is giving the following output during training.

```python
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('main_model_weights_new.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=False, mode='auto',save_weights_only=True)
import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=200, batch_size=100, 
                           validation_data=(testX, testY), 
                           callbacks= [checkpoint]).history).to_csv("history.csv")
```

I was expecting to see the train loss, train accuracy, valid_loss and valid_accuracy. But as shown below it appears there is one more train_loss and train accuracy, output along with the Valid Loss and Valid Accuracy. Can anyone explain me which one to consider as train_loss here?

> Output:
>       Epoch 1/200 2800/2810 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 29.7255 - dense_2_loss_1: 3.9492 - dense_2_loss_2: 5.5785 -
>   dense_2_loss_3: 5.5198 - dense_2_loss_4: 5.6908 - dense_2_loss_5:
>   4.9863 - dense_2_loss_6: 4.0008 - dense_2_acc_1: 0.1711 - dense_2_acc_2: 0.0836 - dense_2_acc_3: 0.0821 - dense_2_acc_4: 0.1200
>   - dense_2_acc_5: 0.2393 - dense_2_acc_6: 0.4171Epoch 00000: saving model to main_model_weights_new.h5 2810/2810
>   [==============================] - 62s - loss: 29.7213 -
>   dense_2_loss_1: 3.9471 - dense_2_loss_2: 5.5732 - dense_2_loss_3:
>   5.5226 - dense_2_loss_4: 5.6907 - dense_2_loss_5: 4.9885 - dense_2_loss_6: 3.9992 - dense_2_acc_1: 0.1715 - dense_2_acc_2: 0.0843
>   - dense_2_acc_3: 0.0822 - dense_2_acc_4: 0.1199 - dense_2_acc_5: 0.2388 - dense_2_acc_6: 0.4167 - val_loss: 31.5189 - val_dense_2_loss_1: 3.6305 - val_dense_2_loss_2: 6.3004 -
>   val_dense_2_loss_3: 5.9689 - val_dense_2_loss_4: 5.5387 -
>   val_dense_2_loss_5: 4.9914 - val_dense_2_loss_6: 5.0890 -
>   val_dense_2_acc_1: 0.2982 - val_dense_2_acc_2: 0.0351 -
>   val_dense_2_acc_3: 0.0351 - val_dense_2_acc_4: 0.1228 -
>   val_dense_2_acc_5: 0.2456 - val_dense_2_acc_6: 0.4035 Epoch 2/200

Comment: Not sure if I got you right - you just want to know the train loss? This is just first metric: `loss: 29.7255`

Comment: @blue-phoenox: Thanks. What makes it confusing is per epoch you can see loss is getting printed twice.loss: 29.7255, loss: 29.7213

Comment: A bit longer ago I used keras last time, but seems very likely to me `2800/2810` represents the number of mini-batches. So `29.7255` was the loss with progress 2800 of 2810 batches and `29.7213` is the final loss at the end of epoch. Therefore the difference. Actually I think the output at step 2800/2810 should be overwritten by the following, no idea why this wasn't the case.